# DirectX 11 Rendering Object Inside out

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I am having alot of struggles trying to follow Frank Luna's book for DirectX 11 3D Programming, and I am currently up to chapter 7 section 2. I have imported the Skull model file and I have begun to render it. The strange thing is that when I am rendering it, it appears to be rendering the back faces over the front facing faces. I am pretty sure this is the case of what is happening. But I am putting forth this question for help and guidance on where I may be going wrong. I will edit this post with inclusions of my code if required to help me figure out where I am going wrong, Thanks alot! (photo's attached)

[Photo - Facing the Skull, Slightly to the Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou8e6.png)

[Photo - Above the Skull, Facing Downwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsjjV.png)

EDIT: I have set a breakpoint in my code for after the first draw call loop and it does not show any faces which are behind the fronts ones, so issue is solved at this frame, but when I continue to the next frame, this is when the problems start.

Comment: Does that model look the same when you modify it's z transformation (move it further)? What value did you specify for near plane and far plane of your frustum?

Comment: It looks like you've set incorrect culling mode when configuring [rasterizer description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am using XMMatrixLookAtLH, should I implement XMMatrixPerspectiveLH?

Comment: @VTT I have tried to change the rasterizer description but those pictures are default with no rasterizer state changes

Comment: After you create rasterizer state you need to apply it for rending pipeline by calling `RSSetState` before drawing mesh. Culling mode switches should be clearly visible. On the other hand this also looks like no depth testing is being performed: look from above suggests that you draw skull first and then teeth on top - if there was a depth test then teeth wouldn't be visible even with incorrect culling.

Comment: @VTT well thats the thing i have not even implemented a rasterizer desc to change the rasterization process at all. Those pictures are completely default in relation to the rasterization process.

Comment: I have a depth buffer which has been set and every draw call is cleared with: mDevContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

Comment: But are you binding it correctly to make depth test to work? You may want to take a look at [Configuring Depth-Stencil Functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what had been causing my grief. I have been using DirectXToolKits SpriteFont and SpriteBatch class's to use the function DrawString to display an FPS counter at the top left corner of the screen, and it must have been messing around with the ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed calls. Thankyou for all your input and brainstorming!!

Comment: You should look at the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch#state-management) for exactly which states ``SpriteBatch`` sets. You should make sure to set any state you rely on, and clear any 'uncleared' stated that would cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the input I'm currently trying to work on a solution

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems are sometimes related to the setup of the `CullMode` in the `D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC`. Try changing from `D3D11_CULL_BACK` to `D3D11_CULL_FRONT` or vice versa. Also have a look at the `FrontCounterClockwise` option of the `D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC`.

Comment: Looking at the picture, I don't think it's because of cull mode